# Boundedness of $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\sin(kx)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds

How do I show that the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\sin(kx)$ is bounded?

In other words:

> Show that there exists a number $B$ such that $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\sin(kx)\right|\leq B$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $x\in I$, where $I$ is a compact interval of $\mathbb{R}$.

---

In the case of $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\sin(kx)$ we can find a telescope sum which delivers a closed form but the $(-1)^{k-1}$ term prevents us from applying this telescope sum technique to this particular series. Maybe there is another approach?

Comment: If you add $\pi$ to $x$, you get the sum of sin series that you know how to simplify.

Comment: Maybe I can be obvious, but the fact that $|\sin(kx)|\leq1$ does not imples the sum is bounded? Because the partial sums are 1 or 0.

Comment: $|a_n|\le 1$ does not imply that the partial sums of $\sum (-1)^n a_n$ are $1$ or $0$.

Comment: @Eric, If I substitute $x:=y+\pi$ then I get $\sin(k(y+\pi))=\sin(ky)\cos(k\pi)+\sin(k\pi)\cos(ky)=\sin(ky)(-1)^k$. Hence, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\sin(k(y+\pi)) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}(-1)^k\sin(ky)= -\sum\limits_{k=1}^n \sin(ky)$. Is this the idea you are proposing?

Comment: Err, yeah, though you don’t need to do sin addition to realize that adding an odd multiple of pi negates the value. And you apparently already know how to simplify the latter, so this has the same properties but is just shifted over by pi.  (Note that the same telescoping trick does work if you just substitute -1 with $e^{i\pi}$)

Answer (score 3):

$(-1)^k\sin(kx)$ is the imaginary part of $(-1)^k e^{kxi} = (-e^{xi})^k$, thus it's enough to show $|\sum_{k=1}^n (-e^{xi})^k| = |-e^{xi}\frac{1-(-e^{xi})^n}{1+e^{xi}}|= |\frac{1-(-e^{xi})^n}{1+e^{xi}}|$ is bounded.

***Update***: We can bound the above uniformly when $x$ is bounded away from $\pi$ (or rather $(2k+1)\pi$), so that $1+e^{xi}$ is bounded away from $0$.

I thought it sould be easy to bound the function around $\pi$, as the function is $0$ around $\pi$. It just occurred to me that **this is actually false**!

First we can establish the Fourier series expansion $\frac{x}{2} = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\sin(kx)}{k}$ over the interval $[-\pi, \pi]$. By Dirichlet's theorem for the convergence of Fourier series, the equality holds for any $x\in (-\pi, \pi)$, while $x=\pi$, the series is obviously $0$. That is, we know the function defined by the series is not continuous over $I = [-\pi, \pi]$. If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^{k-1}\sin(kx)$ is uniformly bounded over $I$, then by Dirichlet's test, $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}\sin(kx)}{k}$ converges uniformly on $I$, thus must be continuous.

So the correct statement should be

> For any compact subset $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ that doesn't include any odd multiple of $\pi$, there exists a number $B_I$ such that $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\sin(kx)\right|\leq B_I$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and all $x\in I$.

---