# When does $\sum_n a_n \sin n x$ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have a sum that converges
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n\sin n x
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Does this imply that $\sum_{n\ge1} |a_n|$ is also convergent?

It seems reasonable to me that this is true, since I imagine that scanning over $x$ would somehow be equivalent to scanning over every possible combination of signs of $a_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but I don't know how to show it.

If it is not true, is there an obvious counter example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not true. To see this consider a series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin nx.$$
Since $$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \sin kx \right|=\left|\mbox{Im} \sum_{k=1}^n e^{ix}\right|=\left|\mbox{Im}\frac{e^{ix}(1-e^{inx} )}{1-e^{ix}}\right|\leq \frac{2}{|e^{ix} -1|}$$ and the sequence $\frac{1}{n}$ is monotone decreasing and tending to $0$ thus the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sin nx.$$ converges for every $x$ by [Dirichlet criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test). But the series  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n} $$ diverges.

Comment: This proof misses the case where $x$ is a multiple of $2\pi$ (although that's a trivial case to be sure in the original problem).

Answer (score 1):

The series $\sum a_n \sin (nx)$ converges at every point if $(a_n)$ decreases to $0$. Ref: p. 112 of Fourier Series by R E Edwards.Taking $a_n=\frac 1 n$ we see that $\sum a_n $ may be $\infty$ when  $\sum a_n \sin (nx)$ converges.

Comment: @martycohen How does it contradict the other answers?

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Take $a_n = \frac{1}{n}$; since $\bigl| \sum_{n=1}^m \sin(nx) \bigr|$ is bounded for any $x$, it follows from [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test) that  $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\sin(nx)$.

Comment: Indeed, this choice of $a_n$ results in a [sawtooth wave](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierSeriesSawtoothWave.html).

Comment: Can you add a reference for the assertion that the partial sums of the sin series are bounded for any fixed $x$?

Comment: A proof is given another answer on this page. You can also see my post at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4284596/boundedness-of-sum-k-1n-1k-1-sinkx/4284609#4284609, or e.g. https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~kazdan/202F09/sum-sin_kx.pdf

Comment: Just to be clear that if $x$ is not an even multiple of $\pi$, use one of the sources. Otherwise, $\sin(kx)=0$ for all $k$.